# I want to encrypt a file from android and decrypt using php suggest me a best algorithm

Tags: php, android, encryption

I am a beginner to android development I want to encrypt a file from android and decrypt using php suggest me a best algorithm. i searched a lot can't reach to a best answer if anyone know pls help me

Comment: i want to encrypt images and video (because its confidential)

Comment: file size upto 500 mb

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're looking for code examples but a good place to start would be an AES symmetric algorithm if you have large files and don't want to deal with any public / private key exchanges.

If you want to go the most secure route possible, use an RSA public/private key pair to encrypt an AES key, and then use the AES key to encrypt your data. That flow would look something like:

`RSA Public Private key Generated --> Data encrypted with AES key --> AES key encrypted with RSA public key --> Encrypted data + encrypted AES key sent as payload`

If you're purely looking for algorithm suggestions and haven't written any code I would personally look to understand these industry standard algorithms first. Encryption can be very tricky and is seldom learned in a day.

Comment: And definitely use an ssl connection (eg. https)